# Подскажите исходник инсталятора на C/C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, opensource

подскажите хороший инсталятор
с открытым кодом на C\C++  буду очень благодарен!

p.s. встречал только на delphi пару штук...

Comment: Зачем на C/C++, чем обычный NSIS не угодил?

Comment: @andreymal, я хочу сделать инсталятор свой т.е. самописный. который, будет проверять сис.требования и кучу других параметров. поэтому ищу какой-то такой open source чтобы использовать. Кроме NSIS какие ещё есть?

Comment: make, nmake, cmake,...

Comment: Ну он же не просит систему сборки, ему нужен инсталлятор, чтобы развернуть свое приложение на компьютере пользователя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использую QtInstallerFramework. Достаточно мощный инструмент, позволяющий кастомизировать свой инсталлятор, также позволяющий организовать доставку обновлений до пользователя.